# Unable to send batch app requests to facebook users

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to send a facebook batch request to an app user by executing the curl command shown below:

`curl -F 'access_token=<FB-APP-ACCESS-TOKEN>' -F 'batch=[{"method":"POST", "relative_url":"<FB-USER-ID>/apprequests", "body":"message=Hi!"}]' https://graph.facebook.com`

But the request is not getting sent.

Response after the curl command is executed:

```
[
{"code":200,"headers":[{"name":"Access-Control-Allow-Origin","value":"*"},
{"name":"Cache-Control","value":"private, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"},
{"name":"Connection","value":"close"},{"name":"Content-Type","value":"text\/javascript; charset=UTF-8"},
{"name":"Expires","value":"Sat, 01 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT"},
{"name":"Pragma","value":"no-cache"}]
,"body":"{\"request\":\"<REQUEST-ID>\",\"to\":[\"<FB-USER-ID>\"]}"}
]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Reference: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/batch/

Answer (score 0):

According to response you provide as a sample your request is sent and having an `id` `<REQUEST-ID>` (which is indicated at the response `body` field for that request in a batch)

Probably your issue isn't the problem to send a request but to display a notification about that request, please note that notification only sent for user-to-user requests and  notification doesn't displayed for app-to-user requests.

Comment: How do I send app notifications as a batch request?

Answer (score 0):

The message "body" should be in the relative URL as a url encoded param called "message"

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/batch/